# url masking and forwarding

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, masking

I have a website running on openshift (xx.rhcloud.com) and I bought a domain name from one of the BIG providers (mydomain.com).
When somebody goes to www.mydomain.com/page1.php I would like the url in the browser to stay as is and the correct page to be loaded.
Here is what happens:

1. If I setup the domain name host with a 301 redirect
   www.mydomain.com/page1.php show as xx.rhcloud.com/page1.php.
2. If I ask for masking (iframe) www.mydomain.com/page1.php becomes www.mydomain.com (the reset of the url never shows)
3. If I setup .htaccess file on the openshift side I'm stuck with "too many redirects" error.
4. I cannot use Cpannel because the server is not hosted by the BIG provided I bought the domain name from.

Please help me figure out what I'm missing and how to fix the problem.

Thanks,
Joanna

Comment: This should be solved with a DNS record set up on the xx.rhcloud.com site. So that the mydomain points to the place the content is hosted.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the http servers buildin proxy feature to use your system as a frontend only.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your ideas? What do I change in the 
DNS setup? What do I do with the proxy server?